# Integrating custom compiled Qt 5 with Visual Studio 2008 (IDE)

Tags: qt

I've compiled Qt 5 for Visual Studio 2008. Now I'd like to integrate the build with VS in order to have project creation wizard, moc tools etc. How can this be done?

(Note this question is not merely about how to use Qt 5 with VS 2008.)

**Edit**

Installing the Visual Studio Add provides adds Qt 5 to the menu and project creation wizards but AFAIK does seem allow the user to choose the path to the Qt binaries. When I try to create a Qt 5 project I getting the error message

[image]

Note that I have already added the path to qt in Projects and Solutions, VC++ Executable Directories.

**Update**

Failed miserably at [compiling the addin](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtVSAddin).

Comment: You need to install the visual studio Qt plug-in.

Comment: The Visual Studio AddIn you mean.
http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/04/11/visual-studio-add-in-1-2-1-for-qt-5-released/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go to Qt->Qt Options->Qt Versions and add a version with path pointing to the qtbase directory you have built. Then set the Default Qt/Win version pointing to the new version you added. Eventually you will need to select the Qt version in Qt Project Settings but probably it will already be set to $(DefaultQtVersion).